# When a mapping $r \rightarrow r^x\;\text{mod } n$ is a permutation of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was studying Blind RSA signature scheme ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature#Blind_RSA_signatures)) where we have a standard RSA setup:

- $p, q$ are some prime numbers
- $n = pq$
- $ed = 1\; \text{mod }\varPhi(n) $

On top of that, there is some random number $r \in Z_n$

In the Wikipedia page it says that a mapping $r \rightarrow r^e\;\text{mod } n$ is a permutation of $\{0,\dotsc,n-1\}$

Could someone explain to me why this is a case? I was trying to figure it out on my own, but I haven't done modular arithmetics in a while. I suspect that in general every mapping $r \rightarrow r^x \;\text{mod } n$, where $x \in Z^*_{\varPhi(n)}$ is a permutation of $\{0,\dotsc,n-1\}$ but I have no clue where it comes from.

Comment: Can you show that it is injective and surjective? Hint: If $ r^e = s^e$, raise both sides to the power $d$.

Comment: Maybe something [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mod%22+AND+%22stack%22+AND+%22permutation%22+site:math.stackexchange.com&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&prmd=invx&sxsrf=AOaemvLUYN2Q3QKc8427ml_zw7sTUAauoQ:1636400800196&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0956DxIn0AhX3_7sIHaV5B8kQrQIoBHoECAMQBQ&biw=412&bih=776&dpr=2.63#ip=1) might help.

Comment: @CalvinLin

I forgot I could just show that that $r \rightarrow r^e$ is a bijection. So for the injective property we have: for every $r,s \in Z_n$ if $r^e = s^e\;\text{mod }n$, then $(r^e)^d = (s^e)^d \;\text{mod }n$ hence $r = s$ so it is injective. For surjective property: for every $s \in Z_n$ there is $r=s^d$ such that $r^e=(s^d)^e = s$. Hence it is a permuation on $\{0,\dotsc,n-1\}$.

Comment: The answers in the linked dupe should answer your question. If not, then please elaborate.